# Python for loop only creates one file

Tags: python, for-loop

So here is my code.  I'm trying to iterate over a bunch of subreddit titles and put them all in separate labeled text files.  If you could help me find a solution that would be great.

```
for entries in subreddit.top(limit=20):
    print (entries.title)
    counter = 0
    with open("file_" + str(counter) + ".txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(str(entries.title))
    counter += 1

    if counter == 20:
        break
```

Comment: I put that in wrong, but in the actual code it's idented

Comment: The if statement is also in the for loop sorry

Comment: Did the loop actually print out more than one title?

Comment: Yes it did, but only made one file

Comment: `io.open` ? what's wrong with just `open` ?

Comment: Huh still didn't open

Comment: oh: you're resetting `counter = 0` in the loop... put that _outside_ the loop!!!

Comment: Oh snap thank you so much :) I feel kinda stupid now I've been stuck for a bit of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you're setting `counter = 0` *in the loop* you're creating several times a file with the same name.

So put `counter = 0` *outside* the `for` loop.

Better method using `enumerate` which yield the index and the element, that you just have to unpack in your loop to get a non-buggy counter which starts at 0, exactly what you need:

```
for counter,entries in enumerate(subreddit.top(limit=20)):
    print (entries.title)
    with open("file_" + str(counter) + ".txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(str(entries.title))
```